# PostgreSQL COPY command with multiple FORCE_QUOTE columns

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to export a table to CSV and force quoting of two columns.

I've tried the following command:

```
COPY hotel_position_daily TO '/home/ubuntu/export/hotel_position_daily.csv' CSV HEADER FORCE_QUOTE hotelname, city;
```

which resulted in

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FORCE_QUOTE"
LINE 1: ...buntu/export/hotel_position_daily.csv' CSV HEADER FORCE_QUOT...
```

and I've tried

```
COPY hotel_position_daily TO '/home/ubuntu/export/hotel_position_daily.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER, FORCE_QUOTE hotelname, city);
```

which resulted in

```
ERROR:  argument to option "force_quote" must be a list of column names
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found the solution to be

```
COPY hotel_position_daily TO '/home/ubuntu/export/hotel_position_daily.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER, FORCE_QUOTE(hotelname, city));
```

Comment: this gives same error `psql -U postgres -d postgres -t -A -F"," -c "COPY (SELECT * FROM solrmaster) to '/tmp/solrmastertest.csv' DELIMITER '|' QUOTE '\"' FORCE_QUOTE {(key, components, docnum)} CSV HEADER"`

Comment: Great answer, the first I'd seen that used `with (...)` - I didn't realize it needed parentheses around multiple, since `... with delimiter ','` worked without parens